The almost sure event in the law of the iterated logarithm for the Brownian motion: what it looks like
I am trying to explicit the almost sure event in the statement of the law of the iterated logarithm. Let us focus on the result about the $\limsup$.
Throughout, let $(\Omega, \mathcal{H}, \mathbb{P})$ be the probability space over which the Brownian motion is defined.
The law of iterated logarithm goes as follows:
Let $h(t): [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined
by $ h(t)=\sqrt{2t \log \log (\frac{1}{t})} $.
Let $(W_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ denote a standard Brownian motion
over the interval $[0,1]$. Then, for almost every $\omega \in \Omega$,
\begin{equation}
    \limsup_{t \rightarrow 0}{\frac{W_t(\omega)}{h(t)}}=1
\end{equation}
So, there is an almost sure event $\Omega_0$ over which the statement holds. My question is: what does such almost sure event look like?
Here's my attempt:
Let $\omega \in \Omega$. Then,
\begin{equation}
    \forall \varepsilon > 0 \quad  \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } |t| \leq \delta \implies \sup_{s \leq t}\bigg( \frac{W_s(\omega)}{h(s)} \bigg) \in [ 1-\varepsilon,  1+ \varepsilon ]
\end{equation}
So, I would like to express this event using a combination of intersections and unions. To ensure that the resulting event is measurable, I am going to exploit the density of $\mathbb{Q}_{+}$ in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ in order to take countably many intersections and unions. The result is as follows:
\begin{equation}
    \Omega_0 = \bigcap_{\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}_{+}} \bigcup_{\delta \in \mathbb{Q}_{+} } \bigcap_{t \in [0,\delta] \cap \mathbb{Q}_{+}} \bigcap_{s \in [0,t]\cap \mathbb{Q}_{+}} \bigg\{ \frac{W_s}{h(s)} \in [ 1-\varepsilon, 1+ \varepsilon ]  \bigg\}
\end{equation}
The restriction on the positive rationals may be harmless or not, but I think one point remains. It seems to me that the intersection over $t \in [0,\delta]$ already satisfies the following intersection, i.e., the one over ${s \in [0,t]}$.
Is this wrong? And if it is correct, then what is the role of the $\sup$ in the statement? I have an idea about this now: given that there are infinitely many instants in $[0,t]$ (albeit countably many, if we restrict ourselves to $\mathbb{Q}_{+}$), if we don't ask for the bound to hold jointly for all $s \leq t$, we might be including in our event even some outcomes $\omega \in \Omega$ where the condition holds or all instants $t$ one by one, but not for their $\sup$ (that's why the last intersection). I really tried hard to find an answer. Do you think my argument is correct?
Any feedback is highly appreciated, thank you.

The event you have captured in more explicit terms is not $\{\limsup_{t\to 0}W_t/h(t)=1\}$, but rather $\{\limsup_{t\to 0}|W_t/h(t)-1|=0\}$. The placement of the absolute value is crucial!

Thank you, good point and I've just edited it. If you have a feedback on what's the impact of the sup (the last intersection) intuitively, I would be grateful.

Because $\sup_{0<s\le t}W_s(\omega)/h(s)$ is monotone in $t$, you have
$$
\{\omega: \limsup_{t\to 0}W_t(\omega)/h(t)\le 1 \} = \cap_{\epsilon\in\Bbb Q_+}\cup_{\delta\in\Bbb Q_+}\cap_{s\in\Bbb Q\cap(0,\delta]}\Big\{\omega:   W_s(\omega)/h(s)\le 1+\epsilon\Big\}
$$
and
$$
\{\omega: \limsup_{t\to 0}W_t(\omega)/h(t)\ge 1 \} = \cap_{\epsilon\in\Bbb Q_+}\cup_{\delta\in\Bbb Q_+}\cap_{t\in\Bbb Q_+\cap(0,\delta]}\cup_{s\in\Bbb Q_+\cap(0,t]}\Big\{\omega:   W_s(\omega)/h(s)\ge 1-\epsilon\Big\}.
$$
